# GWT : Fire and event after javascript and css loads

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt, jsni

I am working on a GWT project and making a JSNI call to a javascript function on some event.

Issue is after my event fires (on tab load), the jsni call to js function is getting called even before the javascript and css have been loaded and so it gives error that function not exists.

What is the best way to handle such a scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to insert the external script in the header of your index.html file (or whatever file serves your gwt nocache file).

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-erternal-js.js"></script>
</header>
```

This way you can be share that the JavaScript file is loaded before GWT tries to call it from JSNI.

Comment: It's important to link your **my-erternal-js.js** before your **.nocache.js** if you follow this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is to inject the script and run your code in a callback that's fired only when the script is finished loading.  [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html) does just that.